# How do I perform a replacement on all files in a zip archive?

Tags: binary-file

I have openend a zip archive with vim (zip.vim v27) and now want to replace a string in all files contained in the archive.

I'm aware that I could manually open all files in buffers and then do `bufdo %s/foo/bar/g | update`, or that I could unpack the archive, execute `` vim `find . -type f` ``, execute the above `bufdo`, and repack the files. Is there anything simpler than that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach is to let your operating system mount the zip file as a directory. Then the problem reduces to applying the transformation to all the files in that directory (and its subdirectories).

Most modern Unix systems (including Linux and OS X) support [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), which allows user code to implement filesystems. For example, you can use [fuse-zip]:

1. Create an empty directory where the zip file will be mounted.

   ```
   mkdir mnt
   ```
2. Mount the zip file to that directory.

   ```
   fuse-zip foo.zip mnt
   ```
3. Read and modify files in `mnt` as desired.
4. When you're done, unmount the zip file from the directory.

   ```
   fusermount -u mnt
   ```

An alternative to fuse-zip is [archivemount](http://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount/). Windows has a [somewhat similar feature](https://superuser.com/questions/367540/tool-to-mount-a-zip-rar-archive-as-a-win-drive-and-be-able-to-read-write-as-a) that allows mounting a zip file as a drive with third-party software.

To act on all the files in a directory tree, you can use [`:args` and `:argdo`](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_multiple_buffers#All_files_in_a_tree).

```
:args mnt/**/*
:argdo %s/foo/bar/g | update
```

Comment: Note that fuse-zip wil stores all changed & added files in memory, and writes them to the zip file on unmount. This is why it's so fast. But has the obvious downsides that 1) It uses a lot of memory with many changes, and 2) it's vital that you don't forget to umount! (which may be a problem if fuse-zip gets killed when  the system runs out of memory due to *1*).